# Resolving a "Formula Analysis Error" when using a recorded macro

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, vlookup, google-sheets-macros

I would like to create a macro which would update the formulas by clicking on a button.

I recorded the following macro with Google Sheets:

```js
function TEST3() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('D2')
             .activate();

  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell()
             .setFormula('=VLOOKUP(A2;Personnel!A1:E15;5;FAUX)');

  spreadsheet.getActiveRange()
             .autoFill(spreadsheet.getRange('D2:D26'), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);

  spreadsheet.getRange('D2:D26')
             .activate();
};
```

But when I bind this script to a button drawing, it does not execute and instead I get

> "Formula Analysis Error"

I think the problem comes from the `VLOOKUP` inside the `setFormula`. At first, I thought the problem was the quotes but I tried other formulas and it worked pretty well, so I am really lost here. I'd gladly appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `FAUX` with `FALSE` or `0`?

Comment: Thank you! You solved my problem! The fact is, using GAS in french, when I recorded the macro it was not VLOOKUP but RECHERCHEV and I changed it only for a communication purpose in this forum. CONCLUSION: this code below is only working in english!

Comment: Good for you that you didn't translate whole formula (and that is was recorded as `FAUX`, not 0) :) Seems that even in excel when you set a formula in macro you have to use english names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, macro recorder uses exact formula you typed (with locale formula names). 
When you set formula in macro, you have to use english names.

Your formula should be like:

```
.setFormula('=VLOOKUP(A2;Personnel!A1:E15;5;FALSE)');
```